# Cadastrar uma lista de registros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc

Bom dia,
Tenho um programa que realiza cadastro de demandas para a produção de uma fabrica, estou com dificuldades em criar uma maneira de fazer com que ele cadastre vários registros vindo de uma lista em uma tabela só.

Exemplo: codigo1 produto1 , codigo2 produto2, codigo3 produto3 ...

Eu queria saber como faço para cadastrar todos de uma vez, gerando um id diferente para cada um.

meu controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(OP model, List<string> observadores, List<string> demanda)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        string EmailObservacao = null;

        if (observadores != null)
        {
            List<string> listaEmailCadastrar = new List<string>();

            foreach (var i in observadores)
            {
                var ObterEmail = AcessoServico.EmailUsuario(i.ToString());

                if (ObterEmail[0].ToString() != "")
                {
                    listaEmailCadastrar.Add(ObterEmail[0].ToString());
                }

            }

            foreach (var item in listaEmailCadastrar)
            {
                EmailObservacao += item.ToString() + ";";

            }

        }


        var resultado = _contexto.OPs.ToList();
        List<OP> listaResultados = new List<OP>();
        foreach (var item in resultado)
        {
            if (model.CodigoProduto == item.CodigoProduto && model.CpfCnpjCliente == item.CpfCnpjCliente)
            {
                listaResultados.Add(item);
            }
        }

        if (listaResultados.Count() > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.ListaResultado = listaResultados.OrderByDescending(p => p.DataCadastro);

            TempData["CadastroExistente"] = $"Já temos solicitações para o cliente {model.CpfCnpjCliente} com o produto {model.CodigoProduto}.";
            TempData["CnpjCpf"] = model.CpfCnpjCliente;
            TempData["CodigoProduto"] = model.CodigoProduto;

           
            #region Preencher formulario
            if (EmailObservacao != null)
            {
                TempData["Observadores"] = EmailObservacao.Remove(EmailObservacao.Length - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Observadores"] = null;
            }

            var obterUsuario = AcessoServico.OrigemUsuario(User.Identity.Name);
            TempData["Departamento"] = obterUsuario[0];
            TempData["Solicitante"] = User.Identity.Name;
            ViewBag.Observadores = new SelectList(AcessoServico.ObterUsuario(_contexto.Permissoes.ToList())).OrderBy(item => item.Text);
            ViewBag.TipoRequisicao = new SelectList(AcessoServico.ListaTipoRequisicao(), "Id");
            ViewBag.ListaDestino = new SelectList(_repositorio.ObterTipoCadastro(User.Identity.Name), "Id", "Tipo");
            ViewBag.ListaPrioridade = new SelectList(AcessoServico.ListaPrioridade());
            #endregion

            return View(model);

        }

        if (EmailObservacao != null)
        {
            model.ObservadoresSolicitante = EmailObservacao.Remove(EmailObservacao.Length - 1);
        }

        model.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
        model.Status = "Aberto";
        _contexto.OPs.Add(model);

        await _contexto.SaveChangesAsync();


        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Sucesso));
    }
```

MEU MODELO:

```
[Table("OP")]
public class OP
{
    [Key]
    [Column("IdOP")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Origem { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    public string Solicitante { get; set; }

    [Column("CodProduto")]       
    public int CodigoProduto { get; set; }

    [Column("DescProduto")]     
    public string DescricaoProduto { get; set; }
    
    [Column("Qtde")]       
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }

    public string CpfCnpjCliente { get; set; }

    [Column("DescCliente")]
    public string DescricaoCliente { get; set; }

    [Column("Obs")]
    public string Observacoes { get; set; }

    public string Prioridade { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string Responsavel { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Prazo { get; set; }

    public string TipoRequisicao { get; set; }

    public int IdTipoCadastro { get; set; }

    public string ObservadoresSolicitante { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("IdTipoCadastro")]
    public TipoCadastro TiposCadastro { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

os produtos estão na listaResultados, se sim, tente fazer dessa forma:
ela vai pecorrer a listaderesultado e vai adicionar produtos por produto.

```
var resultado = _contexto.OPs.ToList();
    List<OP> listaResultados = new List<OP>();
    foreach (var item in resultado)
    {
        if (model.CodigoProduto == item.CodigoProduto && model.CpfCnpjCliente == item.CpfCnpjCliente)
        {
            listaResultados.Add(item);

 if (listaResultados.Count() > 0)
    {
        ViewBag.ListaResultado = listaResultados.OrderByDescending(p => p.DataCadastro);

        TempData["CadastroExistente"] = $"Já temos solicitações para o cliente {model.CpfCnpjCliente} com o produto {model.CodigoProduto}.";
        TempData["CnpjCpf"] = model.CpfCnpjCliente;
        TempData["CodigoProduto"] = model.CodigoProduto;

       
        #region Preencher formulario
        if (EmailObservacao != null)
        {
            TempData["Observadores"] = EmailObservacao.Remove(EmailObservacao.Length - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Observadores"] = null;
        }

        var obterUsuario = AcessoServico.OrigemUsuario(User.Identity.Name);
        TempData["Departamento"] = obterUsuario[0];
        TempData["Solicitante"] = User.Identity.Name;
        ViewBag.Observadores = new SelectList(AcessoServico.ObterUsuario(_contexto.Permissoes.ToList())).OrderBy(item => item.Text);
        ViewBag.TipoRequisicao = new SelectList(AcessoServico.ListaTipoRequisicao(), "Id");
        ViewBag.ListaDestino = new SelectList(_repositorio.ObterTipoCadastro(User.Identity.Name), "Id", "Tipo");
        ViewBag.ListaPrioridade = new SelectList(AcessoServico.ListaPrioridade());
        #endregion

        return View(model);

    }

    if (EmailObservacao != null)
    {
        model.ObservadoresSolicitante = EmailObservacao.Remove(EmailObservacao.Length - 1);
    }

    model.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
    model.Status = "Aberto";
    _contexto.OPs.Add(model);

    await _contexto.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).